# React app works fine but not on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, browser, fetch

My react-redux app works fine on regular browsers but not on mobile browsers. I've used Remote Debugging on Android Devices to check what's going on and I get these 2 errors:

- OPTIONS http://iisnode.local/login 0 ()
- Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

The app makes many fetch requests but I'm afraid that fetch is not supported by chrome mobile. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't seem so. The "failed to fetch" is a failure response to a fetch attempt so the fetch API seems there.

Are you sure your service is supporting the HTTP OPTIONS method? Maybe you are facing a CORS issue: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: @keul There was a cors issue but we got over it using a node proxy server, so I don't think it's that...

Comment: Chrome for android supports fetch API. Why aren't you using error handling if the promise is rejected anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a CORS problem. Make sure the protocol for your requests is "HTTPS". If you are using Node, in your server.js code, use the standard CORS npm package.

Chrome for Android, version 42 onwards supports the fetch API. Why aren't you using error handling if the promise is rejected anyway

Comment: Try going HTTPS.